# encrypt asp.net C# full config file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Web c# asp.net application. I want to encrypt Web.config file. Not only Connection string.

I need full file to encrypt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the following MSDN article, it may be what you are looking for: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx

It is about using the `aspnet_regiis` tool to encrypt sections of the config file, which will be decrypted by IIS/ASP.Net when it is requested by the application.